# How to find intersection of words between two columns A and B in a dataframe and create a new column C

Tags: python-3.x

Find the intersection words in Columns A,B and form Column C and sort it by the words in first column

```py
df['C'] = [set(a).intersection(b) for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]

          A                          B                      C
apple,banana,chikku,grapes      Chikku,Grapes          chikku,Grapes
watermelon,pomo,guava,         pomo,watermelon       watermelon,poma
grapes,lemon,orange            orange,lemon           lemon,orangne
```

Comment: what is the type of `A` and `B` in the original dataframe? `set.intersection` seems like the best way to do it, your original code seems correct

Answer (score 0):

seems correct, what isn't working?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    "A": [set("apple,banana,chikku,grapes".split(",")), set("watermelon,pomo,guava".split(",")),
          set("grapes,lemon,orange".split(","))],
    "B": [set("chikku,grapes".split(",")), set("pomo,watermelon".split(",")), set("orange,lemon".split(","))]
})

df['C'] = [a & b for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]

print(df)
```

Comment: i want it to sort by column values.